# How to write text in multiple columns in rows order

Tags: math-mode, enumerate, multicol

I plan to write a text, for example in 4 columns or variable, in row order. for example see the following text :
[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{tasks}` look after you must, mmmh!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a `tabular` with each cell enumerated using a custom `\newcounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\step}{\protect\stepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter.\ }
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\arraybackslash$\step\displaystyle}l<{$}}

Basic Integration Formulas:\par\medskip
\begin{tabular}{MM}
\int [f(x)\pm g(x)]dx = \int f(x)dx \pm \int g(x)dx  & \int \\
\int ..  &  \int ..\\
\int ..  &  \int ..\\
\int ..  &  \int ..\\
\int ..  &  \int ..\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\newcounter` is setup using the following two lines:

```
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand{\step}{\protect\stepcounter{mycounter}\themycounter.\ }
```

and you can automate the whole process of enumeration plus math mode inputs via defining a `\newcolumntype{M}` like this:

```
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\arraybackslash$\step\displaystyle}l<{$}}
```

The `array` package is to be loaded for this command. You are free, then, to choose the number of columns, `\displaystyle`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Horizontal enumerated lists are easy with the `tasks` package. Use `\begin{tasks}(4)\task ... \end{task}` to build up a list with 4 tasks per row (or four 'columns') -- the `tasks` environment has an optional arguments, see the manual for the options.

Please fill in the integrals yourself ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
Basic Integration Formulas
\end{center}
\begin{tasks}[counter-format={tsk[1].}](4)   % tsk[1] will use arabic numbers
\task $\int$
\task $\int$
\task $\int$
\task $\int$
\task $\int$
\task $\int$
\task $\int$
\task $\int$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]